# Cartesian Product of Anonymous type

Tags: c#, json, linq

I am working on code which will give Cartesian product of two anonymous types. These 2 anonymous types are generated from database.

**Code for 1st anonymous type:**

```
 private IEnumerable<object> GetItem()
    {
        return _unitOfWork.GetRepository<Item>()
            .ListAll()
            .Select(x => new
            {
                itemId = x.Id,
                itemName = x.Name
            })
    }
```

**Code for 2nd anonymous type:**

```
private IEnumerable<object> GetVenue()
    {
        return _unitOfWork.GetRepository<Venue>()
            .ListAll()
            .Select(x => new
            {
                locationName = x.Address.City,
                venueId = x.VenueId,
                venueName = x.Name
            })
    }
```

I have following method to get the data and perform Cartesian product and return the data.

```
public object GetRestrictLookupInfo(IEnumerable<int> lookupCombinations)
    {
        IEnumerable<object> restrictList = new List<object>();
        if (lookupCombinations.Contains(1))
        {
            var tempProductProfileList = GetItem();
            restrictList = tempProductProfileList.AsEnumerable();
        }
        if (lookupCombinations.Contains(2))
        {
            var tempProductGroupList = GetVenue();
            restrictList = (from a in restrictList.AsEnumerable()
                            from b in tempProductGroupList.AsEnumerable()
                            select new { a, b });
        }
        return restrictList;
    }
```

I have controller which calls this method and return data in json format.

**Controller Code**

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetData(IEnumerable<int> lookupCombinations)
    {
        var lookupRestrictInfo = _sellerService.GetRestrictLookupInfo(lookupCombinations);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, lookupRestrictInfo);
    }
```

**Response expected is:-**

```
[  {  
     "itemId": 1,  
     "itemName": "Music",        
     "locationName": "Paris",  
     "venueId": 99,  
     "venueName": "Royal Festival Hall"  
}  ]
```

**Response which I receive is**

```
[  {  
"a": {  
  "itemId": 1,  
  "itemName": "Music"        
},  
"b": {  
  "locationName": "Paris",  
  "venueId": 99,  
  "venueName": "Royal Festival Hall" }  }]
```

I am not able to get the expected JSON string.

Comment: Not sure how you would accomplish this other than using reflection to iterate over the members of each anonymous type or explicitly constructing a new anonymous type by specifying the members of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to produce a single item in the output you need to create a new type, named or anonymous. Since you are using `object`s rather than actual types, the quickest approach is to cast them to `dynamic`:

```
var tempProductGroupList = GetVenue();
restrictList = (from a in restrictList.Cast<dynamic>()
                from b in tempProductGroupList.Cast<dynamic>()
                select new {
                    itemId = (int)a.itemId,  
                    itemName = (string)a.itemName,        
                    locationName = (string)b.locationName,  
                    venueId = (int)b.venueId,  
                    venueName = (string)b.venueName
                });
```

This code is tightly coupled to the code producing both lists, because it assumes the knowledge of the field names of types passed into it dynamically. Any change in the structure of source data must be followed by a change in the code making combinations. In addition, it defeats run-time checking, so you need to be very careful with this code.

Answer (score 1):

You should start with the simplest possible code that shows your problem; your code above has a lot of complexities that may (or may not) have anything to do with your problem.  Is this about manipulating anonymous types? Doing a Cartesian product with LINQ? Converting an `object` to JSON?

Here's one possible answer to what you might be looking for; notice that you can pass around anonymous types using generics instead of `object`.

```
namespace AnonymousTypes
{
    class Program
    {
        static string Serialize(object o)
        {
            var d = (dynamic)o;
            return d.ItemId.ToString() + d.ItemName + d.VenueId.ToString() + d.LocationName + d.VenueName;
        }
        static string GetData<T>(IEnumerable<T> result)
        {
            var retval = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var r in result)
                retval.Append(Serialize(r));
            return retval.ToString();
        }
        static string GetRestrictLookupInfo()
        {
            var restrictList = new[] { new { Id = 1, Name = "Music" }, new { Id = 2, Name = "TV" } };
            var tempProductGroupList = new[] { new { LocationName = "Paris", Id = 99, Name = "Royal Festival Hall" } };
            var result = from item in restrictList
                         from venue in tempProductGroupList
                         select new
                         {
                             ItemId = item.Id,
                             ItemName = item.Name,
                             LocationName = venue.LocationName,
                             VenueId = venue.Id,
                             VenueName = venue.Name
                         };
            return GetData(result);
        }

        public static string GetData()
        {
            return GetRestrictLookupInfo();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = GetData();
        }
    }
}
```

If that's not what you're looking for, you might start with code that doesn't use anonymous types, such as

```
namespace AnonymousTypes
{
    sealed class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    sealed class Venue
    {
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    sealed class ItemAndVenue
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
        public int VenueId { get; set; }
        public string VenueName { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static IEnumerable<Item> GetItem()
        {
            return new[] { new Item { Id = 1, Name = "Music" } };
        }

        static IEnumerable<Venue> GetVenue()
        {
            return new[] { new Venue { LocationName = "Paris", Id = 99, Name = "Royal Festival Hall" } };
        }

        static IEnumerable<ItemAndVenue> GetRestrictLookupInfo()
        {
            var restrictList = GetItem();
            var tempProductGroupList = GetVenue();
            var result = from item in restrictList
                    from venue in tempProductGroupList
                    select new ItemAndVenue
                    {
                        ItemId = item.Id,
                        ItemName = item.Name,
                        LocationName = venue.LocationName,
                        VenueId = venue.Id,
                        VenueName = venue.Name
                    };
            return result;
        }

        static string GetData()
        {
            var v = GetRestrictLookupInfo().First();
            return v.ItemId.ToString() + v.ItemName + v.VenueId.ToString() + v.LocationName + v.VenueName;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = GetData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not post an answer to request clarification of the question, or to point out problems with the question.  An answer is where you post an *answer* to the question.  You should be using comments to ask clarifying questions or point out problems with the question, and you should be voting to close the question if you are unclear as to what it is actually asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a simple object instead of nesting:

`select new { a.itemId, a.itemName, b.locationName }`

Answer (score 0):

Like an option:

```
public object GetRestrictLookupInfo(IEnumerable<int> lookupCombinations)
{
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> result = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    if (lookupCombinations.Contains(1))
    {
        var tmp = _unitOfWork.GetRepository<Item>()
                             .ListAll()
                             .Select(x => new
                             {
                                 itemId = x.Id,
                                 itemName = x.Name
                             })
                             .Select(x => 
                             {
                                 var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                                 dic.Add(nameof(x.itemId), x.itemId);
                                 dic.Add(nameof(x.itemName), x.itemName);

                                 return dic;
                             });

        result.AddRange(tmp);
    }
    if (lookupCombinations.Contains(2))
    {
        var tmp = _unitOfWork.GetRepository<Venue>()
                             .ListAll()
                             .Select(x => new
                             {
                                 locationName = x.Address.City,
                                 venueId = x.VenueId,
                                 venueName = x.Name
                             })
                             .Select(x => 
                             {
                                 var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                                 dic.Add(nameof(x.locationName), x.locationName);
                                 dic.Add(nameof(x.venueId), x.venueId);
                                 dic.Add(nameof(x.venueName), x.venueName);

                                 return dic;
                             });

        result = result.SelectMany(r => tmp.Select(t => r.Concat(t)));
    }

    return result;
}
```

It looks like some magic. I uses dictionary instead of object. It can be make in more clear way (extract few methods), but the idea should be clear.

Then, during serialization it will be presented as you need.